# JQuery: Drop only the latest draggable div then previously dropped div append to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I be able to drop only the latest draggable div to a container div and the previous or the placed over div will directly append to another container div. For example, I have 2 droppable div named container1 and container2, and 2 draggable div named draggable1 and draggable2. Assuming that draggable1 is already dropped at container1 from container2, I will now drag draggable2 to container1 then as it is dropped, draggable1 must append directly to container2.

Html

```
<div class="container1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
<div class="container2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="draggable1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
   <div class="draggable2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.draggable1 .draggable2').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    snap: '#wrapper',
    containment: document.body,
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    appendTo: document.body
});
$('.container1 .container2').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable1 .draggable2',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'));
        //something here
    }
});
```

**Update**

Recently, I have done some research and I found this source which is similar and likely to be a guide. However, Im getting confused with it. Please help.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsmacaalay/fM63u/)

Comment: Basically, you need to make the script know when some div was dropped in order to conditionally drop the others.
Please, can you make a working demo?

Comment: @Frondor Please see above update, I look towards your input. Thank you

Comment: There's no method to programmaticaly place an element into another container, but you can disable the ones already "filled". If I understood correctly, you want to add elements into containers but: 1) you don't want to move them **between** containers. 2) you want them not to "**stack**" on the same container. ---- If that's ok, I can try an example for you

Comment: Assuming I understand the question correctly, you have solved it properly in the fiddle.

Comment: @CodeToad Its a bit similar but the code in the fiddle refers to positioning. Im a beginner at web dev so i dont really understand it much and I know you can provide me much better and straight towards my requirement .

Comment: What changes would you like to make to fiddle to make it behave as expected?